# how to stop metal hooks in ends of side rails of wooden bed from squeaking

Tags: wooden-furniture

I have an all wooden bed with two wooden side rails that have metal hooks at the ends for hooking them into the connections inside the headboard/footboard. The bed squeaks badly. I've tried wedging thin cardboard pieces at the end of each side rail/bed frame connection, but they work loose and the bed starts squeaking again. Any ideas for a remedy?

Comment: An image would help...

Comment: lubrication, such as candle wax

Comment: Are the rails made for the head board ?  My bed had to tap with rubber mallet to tighten up and mallet to take apart.  And little wax may help .

Answer (score 1):

You could try lithium grease, but paraffin wax is less messy ;)